# OneToOne mapping without discriminator or hierarchy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, one-to-one

I have two tables in a legacy database and am trying to create a Java model on it (using **JPA 2.0** and Hibernate 4)

```
create table master (
  master_id                      number(38) not null, --this is the primary key 
  ...
)

create table child (
  master_id                      number(38) not null, --the primary key and also a foreign key to master.id
  ...
)
```

I've created the entities but am thoroughly confused about which annotations to use on each class. `@JoinColumn? @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn? @Id`?

What I know is that `Master` will manage the persistence in the Java layer. That is, persists and updates will be cascaded from `Master`. This must be a basic question, but I'm new to JPA.

```
@Entity
class Master {

  @Id
  @Column (name="master_id")

  @OneToOne
  private Child child;

}

@Entity
class Child {

  @OneToOne
  private Master master;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below:

```
@Entity
class Master {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "master")
    private Child child;
}

@Entity
class Child {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "master_id")
    private Master master;
}
```

Further information:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear, child.master_id is the PK as well, not just a foreign key. I'll edit the main question.

Comment: It eventually worked with @MapsId, as suggested in http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.ca/2014/05/onetoone-with-shared-primary-key.html